# You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on Case

Tags: trigger, validation

While creating a validation rule the have got this error(You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on Case), can i have a trigger used instead.

Comment: You will need to provide more information, what's the validation you are trying to achieve and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 3):

When you hit the 10 cross-object reference limit it can be a warning that you are reaching a level of complexity that's stretching the limits of the formula engine. Although you can request the limit to be increased through Salesforce support, the limit doesn’t go much higher (at this time), so it's also time to consider moving logic into Apex.

If you have hit the limit, here are suggestions to free up some of your references:

- Consider if there are other ways to expose data in formula fields. For example if you want to see information on an object 1-2 levels away on an object’s detail page but not report on it, you can require users to hover over the lookup link to view the details.
- If you have multiple references to the same type of object (for example, you reference four different contacts in formula fields, each with a different purpose), consider creating a junction object so you can display the referenced objects in a related list.
- If you have references that are only used in validation rules, rewrite those rules as an Apex trigger.
- If any of the references are used by only one component, convert that to a trigger.
- If you are spanning multiple levels of a hierarchy such as parent accounts, cases, or a hierarchy of custom objects, see if it’s possible to flatten the hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a trigger. A better option might be to contact support. This is a soft limit and support can increase it if you have a good use case.

Answer (score 0):

This limit is checked across all validation rules, formula fields, workflow formulas, report formulas, and approval process formulas for the Case object.

Do some research to see where other cross-object formulas are being used (or overused) for the Case object to see if you can gain some back.

It is a feature that can be provisioned, but not to an unlimited amount. You might want to get a handle on this before it takes you over.