# Account owner formula field

Tags: formula, account, fields, ownership

In order to remove the 'Change' link near the Owner in the Account Page Layout, a possibile solution for us was to create a text formula field showing only the Owner First Name + Last Name. Should be easy, BUT: I am trying with `Owner.FirstName & " " & Owner.LastName` and I get this error:

```
You have reached the maximum number of 10 object references on Account
You must remove at least 1 relationship(s) in order to save this Formula Field.
Related objects referenced in this Formula Field:

Owner
```

plus a reference to an awful formula field created i-dont-know-when by someone else that I cannot modify. I just want to understand: is the problem the other formula field or mine? Shouldn't the Account Owner be available for formulas since Spring '13? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is a soft limit on the number of formulas that you can use per object. This limit is based on your Salesforce edition. There are limits all across Salesforce from both a configuration and development perspective.

You can request that you have this soft limit increased from '10' to a higher limit. This request should be made either via Premier Support or via your Salesforce account manager. For example, the soft limit of fields per object that can be marked for tracking history is typically 20 but this can be increased to as much as 50. From [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000goYOAAY), it seems that the limit could be increased to 20 or more.

However, just because the soft limit can be increased, it doesn't mean that it should. This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49539/you-have-reached-the-maximum-number-of-10-object-references-on-case) from Salesforce Stack Exchange gives some useful detail.

As for why you cannot edit the other formula, it would be worthwhile checking to see if it is a dependency for an installed package. Of course, you can also a log a case to Premier Support.

Thanks

Comment: So do you think this is caused by the other formula? Cause I was able to create other formula fields on Account after that monster was created :( thanks for your answer

Comment: Are those formulas related to other objects? Your formula in this question is related to the Owner object (User). Your formula in this question is a cross-object formula: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_cross_object.htm&language=en_US

Comment: No, the other formula is related to the Parent Account

Comment: Right, so because your formula in this question (Owner.FirstName & " " & Owner.LastName) is related to Owner, it is a cross object formula and you cannot create it because you are already at the limit of cross object formulas. If the other formula you created is not a cross object formula, then that would explain why you could successfully save that formula. The limit you are hitting is related to cross object formulas, I believe. More info in the aforementioned link.